# Django Fastcgi stop responding

Tags: python, django, nginx, fastcgi

I have a problem with django. I use django (runfcgi) + nginx but for 1-2 times a day the fastcgi process stops responding.

In the nginx error logs I see initially errors of type 110 (Timeout) and then 111 (Bad Gateway) so I am forced to restart the django server.

How can I understand why django stops responding?

I use prefork method and the latest django/nginx version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem Switching to Django+ Nginx+ Gunicorn fixed the problem for me [Link](http://gunicorn.org/)